# R-Error reading data()

Tags: r

I'm using the packages `survival`, `Kmsurv`, and when I run:

```
data(aids)
```

It has the following error. The thing is, I didn't create this data, it came with the lib so I don't know why isn't it working?

[image: rstudio_error]

Comment: What are the versions of the packages? It works fine here. I'm using: > packageVersion("survival")
[1] ‘2.39.5’
> packageVersion("KMsurv")
[1] ‘0.1.5’

Comment: Do the other data items in KMsurv work? `data(package="KMsurv")` will list them. If not, then your R might have a problem with gzip files. Try the example codes in ?connections that work with gz files and see what happens. If its just the one data from the package then it might be corrupted in some way....

Comment: ``Kmsurv`` is incorrectly spelled. It's ``KMsurv``.

Comment: @CyrusMohammadian not in the screenshot.